# Factoring out a custom button in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm a beginner in Vue and I'm trying to understand how to make use of custom components. I have a simple Vue app which looks as follows:

.html

```
<div id="app1">
    <button
    v-for="(button, index) in buttons"
    v-bind:key="button"
    v-on:click="buttonClick(index)"
    >
    {{ button }}
    </button>
</div>
```

.js

```
const app1 = new Vue({
    el: '#app1',
    data: { buttons: ['A', 'B', 'C', ] },
    methods: { buttonClick: (i) => console.log(i) },
})
```

### When the buttons are clicked, their corresponding index is logged to console.

I want to refactor this by making a custom button component instead, so I attempted to change this to the following

.html (`*` is changed line)

```
<div id="app2">
    <custom-button
    v-for="(button, index) in buttons"
    v-bind:key="button"
    v-on:click="buttonClick(index)"
*   v-bind:content="button",
    >
    {{ button }}
    </custom-button>
</div>
```

.js

```
Vue.component('custom-button', {
    props: ['content'],
    template: '<button> {{ content }} </button>'
})
```

(The app is unchanged except `'#app1'` is now `'#app2'`)

When these buttons are clicked, no function is called (the buttons don't even have an event listener). So this approach clearly doesn't work, so I'm wondering how the correct approach would be?

(Ideally I would like the method to remain on the app, if possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using native events on custom components, you need the `native` event modifier:

```
<div id="app2">
    <custom-button
    v-for="(button, index) in buttons"
    v-bind:key="button"
 *  v-on:click.native="buttonClick(index)"
    v-bind:content="button",
    >
    {{ button }}
    </custom-button>
</div>
```

[This is the page of the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) explaining this feature.